# cv2.imshow cutting off numbers at the bottom of screen

Tags: python, image, opencv

The code I'm running below displays the picture I have posted beneath it. It is simple: the numbers are being cut off from the `imshow()` display. Why is this happening?

```
import cv2 as cv
try:
    from PIL import Image
except ImportError:
    import Image
import pytesseract as ocr
import re

image1 = cv.imread("../photos/red.png")
gray1 = cv.cvtColor(image1, cv.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
cv.imshow("gray1", gray1)
cv.waitKey(0)
cv.destroyAllWindows()
```

[image: The numbers at the bottom are cut off in this picture]

Here is the origninal picture:

[image: original]

Comment: you can give the original picture for good analysis?

Comment: @DaniloMercadoOudalova I added it.

Comment: Huh? There are no numbers at all on the original.

Comment: yeah, there is no numbers. what numbers cut off?

Comment: cv2.imshow() displays a window with numbers at the bottom that correspond to the pixel that the cursor is hovering over. This information includes pixel position and color.

Comment: No update?  I'm having this same issue.  I reckon it has something to do with my Windows DPI scaling being set to 150%, but I don't want to change it for everything else.